# How to highlight at DOM the last row added to state variable with VueJS

Tags: css, vuejs2, vue-router

I am making a small CMS with Vue-Router and Firebase. The CMS has a section with the post list. When the user press the button to create new post, open a child component with the editor.

When the user saves the post, the child leaves and returns to the post list. I would like the added row to have a color highlight applied with CSS for a few seconds.

I know how to do the highlight effect with CSS class but I do not know how to apply that CSS class only to that new row with VueJS. Do you give me any suggestions or ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your code (at least the loop-part). Also check out this question, maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46218307/vue-js-how-to-get-last-child-ref-in-v-for-children-components

Comment: It's too much code to show here but maybe I can try with $refs. Thanks @elveti

Comment: I don't know if I'm understanding well, but if the new row is the last one of your list, then why not using css last-child property ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply your question: do sth in parent when sth has been handled in child component.
See [vm.$emit](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#vm-emit)